# Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent Poisson distributed random variables with means $\lambda$, $\mu$ respectively. $Z=XY$. Find the pmf of $Z$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

This was asked on a stats test I just took, and I'm convinced it's a typo and should have been $X+Y$, which has a well-known answer. Here is my best guess at the PMF of $Z=XY$
$$ P(Z=z) = P(XY=z) = P(X=\frac{z}{y})P(Y=y) \forall y \text{ s.t. } y\mid z $$
$$ P(Z=z) = e^{-\lambda-\mu} \sum_{i=1}^z \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
             \frac{\lambda^{\frac{z}{i}}\mu^i}{\frac{z}{i}!i!} & \text{if} \quad i|z. \\
             0 & \text{else}
        \end{array}
    \right. $$

Unless I'm missing something huge, I don't think there's a way to simplify this further into a nice equation, is there?

Comment: What happens when $Y=0$?

Comment: @Math1000 good point. I suppose I’d have to add another clause to the pmf to cover $P[Z=0]$. But if we assume Z>1 is there a nicer solution than that ugly mess I put? I mean this was a low-value test question. It seemed like there was a simpler answer...